# Add number of working days to Date in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to add no. of business days to a date field.

Below is my logic, this is not working if day falls on Monday and if no. of days are more than 5.

```
dateadd(DAY, 
        (iff(dayofweek(to_date(Start_Date_Column) ) = 1, 0 ,
(TRUNCATE(((dayofweek(to_date(Start_Date_Column)) + No_DAYS - 1)/5)) * 2)) + No_DAYS) , to_date(Start_Date_Column));
```

e.g.. For the below scenario the date is moving to 2021-01-09(which is Saturday) instead of monday(2021-01-11)

```
 select
         
          dateadd(DAY, 
        (iff(dayofweek(to_date('2021-01-04') ) = 1, 0 ,
(TRUNCATE(((dayofweek(to_date('2021-01-04')) + 5 - 1)/5)) * 2)) + 5) , to_date('2021-01-04'))
```

Comment: Try using next_day(date_col,'Monday')

Comment: Are you only accounting for weekends as non-business days? What about holidays?

Comment: Yes,, i want to add only weekends..

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTE to get next business day, after adding specific number of business days to a date.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
biz_day (rown, dt) AS
(
SELECT 1,'2022-05-07'::date
union all
SELECT
case when dayname(dateadd(day,1,dt)) not in ('Sat','Sun')
then rown+1
else rown end ,
dateadd(day,1,dt)
from biz_day where rown <= $No_DAYS
)
SELECT min(dt) orig_dt,max(dt) nxt_biz_date FROM biz_day;
```

| ORIG_DT | NXT_BIZ_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-07 | 2022-05-20 |

Original table -
Column next_dy to be modified with next business day, based on specific number of days (e.g. 10)

```
select * from dates;
```

| DY | NEXT_DY |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-05 | NULL |
| 2022-05-09 | NULL |
| 2022-05-11 | NULL |
| 2022-05-14 | NULL |
| 2022-05-15 | NULL |
| 2022-05-17 | NULL |
| 2022-05-27 | NULL |

(UDF) Function creation including recursive CTE for getting next biz day -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_b_date(dt date,no_day number)
RETURNS date
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
WITH RECURSIVE
biz_day (rown, cte_dt) AS
(
SELECT 1,dt
union all
SELECT
case when dayname(dateadd(day,1,cte_dt)) not in ('Sat','Sun')
then rown+1
else rown end ,
dateadd(day,1,cte_dt)
from biz_day where rown <= no_day
)
SELECT max(cte_dt) nxt_biz_date FROM biz_day
$$;
```

Anonymous Block to call function and update source table -

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  p_dt date;
  n_dt date;
  no_days number;
  c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT dy FROM dates;
BEGIN
 
  for record in c1 do
  p_dt:=record.dy;
  no_days:=10;
  n_dt:=(select next_b_date(:p_dt,:no_days));
  update dates set next_dy = :n_dt where dy=:p_dt;
  end for;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$$
;
```

Table after running the update -

```
select * from dates;
```

| DY | NEXT_DY |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-05 | 2022-05-19 |
| 2022-05-09 | 2022-05-23 |
| 2022-05-11 | 2022-05-25 |
| 2022-05-14 | 2022-05-27 |
| 2022-05-15 | 2022-05-27 |
| 2022-05-17 | 2022-05-31 |
| 2022-05-27 | 2022-06-10 |

Below can also be used, which has little-bit of hard-coding
i.e. multiply number of days with 3 to go bit over extra in days
(to compensate for intermediate sat/sun) for fetching business days.

```
set no_days=11;

update dates dt1 set next_dy = dt2.n_dy from
(
with cte1 as
(select row_number() over (partition by dy order by seq4()) rn,dy,
dateadd(day,rn,dy) day1 from dates, 
table(generator(rowcount=>$no_days*3))), cte2 as
(select row_number() over (partition by dy order by seq4()) rn,dy,day1 
from cte1 where dayname(day1) 
not in ('Sat','Sun') )
select dy,max(day1) n_dy from cte2 where rn<=$no_days 
group by dy order by dy
) dt2
where dt1.dy = dt2.dy;
```

Table after update -

```
select * from dates;
```

| DY | NEXT_DY |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-05 | 2022-05-20 |
| 2022-05-09 | 2022-05-24 |
| 2022-05-11 | 2022-05-26 |
| 2022-05-14 | 2022-05-30 |
| 2022-05-15 | 2022-05-30 |
| 2022-05-17 | 2022-06-01 |
| 2022-05-27 | 2022-06-13 |

Old - solution (not valid) to add days and move to next Monday -

To get next business day, check if day after adding is sat or sun and if so, get to next Monday using function `next_day`

Query with some test-data:

```
with date_cte(bizday) as
(select * from values
('2022-05-05'::date),
('2022-05-11'::date),
('2022-05-14'::date),
('2022-05-15'::date),
('2022-05-21'::date),
('2022-05-27'::date)
)
select bizday orig_date,dayname(bizday) orig_day,
$No_DAYS No_days,
dateadd(day,$No_DAYS,bizday) next_day,
case when dayname(dateadd(day,$No_DAYS,bizday)) = 'Sat'
then next_day(dateadd(day,$No_DAYS,bizday),'Monday')
when dayname(dateadd(day,$No_DAYS,bizday)) = 'Sun'
then next_day(dateadd(day,$No_DAYS,bizday),'Monday')
else dateadd(day,$No_DAYS,bizday) end next_b_day,
dayname(next_b_day) next_b_dayname
from date_cte;
```

| ORIG_DATE | ORIG_DAY | NO_DAYS | NEXT_DAY | NEXT_B_DAY | NEXT_B_DAYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-05 | Thu | 10 | 2022-05-15 | 2022-05-16 | Mon |
| 2022-05-11 | Wed | 10 | 2022-05-21 | 2022-05-23 | Mon |
| 2022-05-14 | Sat | 10 | 2022-05-24 | 2022-05-24 | Tue |
| 2022-05-15 | Sun | 10 | 2022-05-25 | 2022-05-25 | Wed |
| 2022-05-21 | Sat | 10 | 2022-05-31 | 2022-05-31 | Tue |
| 2022-05-27 | Fri | 10 | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-06 | Mon |

Refer for [date-time](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#supported-date-and-time-parts)

Also, you might need to add more here as the definition of a business day can be varied.

Comment: But this is not working if no. Days are 10

Comment: There does not seem to be a direct or easy way to update this. One way is recursive CTE. I have added one possible approach in the solution, see if that helps and can be used in your case.

Comment: Yea I created cursor but it is running long time on entire table,. I'm getting  this error while using cte ' Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated'..

Comment: while using cte function, i think there is a bug in snowflake . Getting an error as 'Unsupported subquery'

Comment: Its not a bug, you cannot use CTE function directly in query. Please refer to the answer for usage of  function else use the other update that has hard-coding for weekend extrapolation.